# Cannot add instagram test users in Instagram Basic Display API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have been creating an app in MetaForDevelopers, and I have added Instagram Basic Display as a product to the app. After configuring the app based on the following documentation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started iam getting stuck at step 3, where you add an instagram test user. The problem is, when i type in my account username and click on "Add" I get the following error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkAYV.png)

I have checked all the steps and I'm following the exact steps given in the doc still I'm stuck here.

Comment: did you find any solution? I have the same problem as you

Comment: no i didnt, every documentations says the same steps, it just doesnt work

Comment: It used to work, it no longer works. Even pre-existing apps no longer work either to invite testers. Been like this all week.